# Is using innodb_file_per_table improve speed of alter table command?

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, alter-table, performance-tuning

As `innodb_file_per_table` option separates table files instead of putting all data and indexes of DBs into one ibdata file, is using this option improve speed of alter table?

I have a table of 40M rows and when I alter a specific table it takes about 5 to 6 hours.

Does this solution help? Is there other ways around to improve alter table speed on heavy tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innodb_file_per_table` is convenient option to manage disk space used by innodb, but it won't improve ALTER TABLE time.

As of 5.6 InnoDB supports online DDL for some kind of ALTERs. Check [Online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html) page to see what's currently supported.

If not, you may consider using pt-online-schema-change or similar tool(https://github.com/github/gh-ost, https://github.com/facebookincubator/OnlineSchemaChange). It will run long time, but won't block the table.